# Django processes concurrency

Tags: django, python-3.x, concurrency

I am running a Django app with 2 processes (Apache + mod_wsgi).
When a certain view is called, the content of a folder is read and the process adds entries to my database based on what files are new/updated in the folder.

When 2 such views execute at the same time, both see the new file and both want to create a new entry. I cannot manage to have only one of them write the new entry.

I tried to use `select_on_update`, `with transaction.atomic()`, `get_or_create`, but without any success (maybe used wrongly?).

What is the proper way of locking to avoid writing an entry with the same content twice with `get_or_create` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up enforcing the unicity at the database (model) level, and catching the resulting `IntegrityError` in the code.